# Help identifying mysterious communications tower

Tags: rf, antenna, telecommunications, cellular

There's a tower near my house that I thought was a cell tower, but I noticed it's not registered on the FCC map.  Can anyone help me ID what type of tower this might be?  I was thinking it was a cellular base-station, but it seems kinda small.

Thanks in advance!

[google maps link](https://goo.gl/maps/F5ZAwRqgvcfrxsGk6)

[image]

Comment: Just walk in and ask?

Comment: Cell tower, with a short mast. There's a taller one a few blocks south on Copper Ave, google map link https://www.google.com/maps/@35.0791398,-106.49806,3a,41.3y,64.12h,104.22t/data=!3m9!1e1!3m7!1sr4NYNMlVQv0DYvOu1XQn6g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!9m2!1b1!2i43 -- think since the highway is pretty flat and level, and there's a mountain range on one side, they went with lower-than-normal cell towers to serve the highway and surrounding residential areas.

Comment: This is also not far from Sandia national labs, so they probably opted for shorter masts and more cells, to get better control of the covered area and avoid unwanted RF closer to the active areas of the laboratory.

Comment: This could be a small cell base station antenna. Here are some examples of disguised cellphone base station antennas. https://twistedsifter.com/2012/08/examples-of-cell-phone-tower-disguises/

Comment: @jonk walk in... where?

Comment: The consensus seems to be a cell tower, thanks for your help, guys!